# Audio is not being transferred to other user in the webrtc connection, it's just getting back to the same user what should i do so that it works well?

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, real-time

I'm building a live peer-to-peer video calling app with Reactjs, Socketio, and WebRTC at http://p2prealtime.vercel.app/. However,
I'm having trouble with the audio—it's not going to the other user but it is looping back to the sender. how can i solve this issue?

Full Code Link: https://dub.sh/H6ZHrth

**Code I have tried:**

```
window.navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then(async (stream) => {
    setVideoStream(stream);
  });
```

I have added this code to get audio and video and also added audio stream to the PC but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

in pc.addTrack function to include the audio track from the videoStream

```
pc.addTrack(videoStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
pc.addTrack(videoStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
```

also in pc.ontrack function to handle both video and audio tracks

```
pc.ontrack = (e) => {
  const tracks = e.streams[0].getTracks();
  tracks.forEach((track) => {
    if (track.kind === "video") {
      setRemoteVideoStream(new MediaStream([track]));
    } else if (track.kind === "audio") {
      // Handle the remote audio stream here
    }
  });
};
```

then modify the pc.onicecandidate function to emit the ICE candidate for both audio and video

```
pc.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
  s.emit("iceCandidateReply", { candidate });
};
```

after all this the server-side code, make sure that the ICE candidates for both audio and video are properly handled and transmitted to the remote user.